# How can i do a placeholder Label more elegant?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to do a placeholder Lable so that my two Entery boxes are on the same row but have some space between them. This is my current solution and i think it isnt the most perfect one but i have no idea how to do it better

Here my Code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry("1000x600")
root.config(bg = "#524D4C")

def getvalue():
    return

frame = tk.Frame(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg= "#524D4C")

rolls = tk.Entry(frame,)
sides = tk.Entry(frame,)
place_hold = tk.Label(frame, text="             ", bg= "#524D4C")


frame.pack(pady=(300,0))
rolls.grid(row=0, column=0)
place_hold.grid(row=0, column=1)
sides.grid(row=0, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see what is happening, maybe include a screenshot.

Comment: If you want the two entries to be on the same column, why are you explicitly giving them different column numbers? Did you mean to say "row", and are you asking  how to have a little padding between two widgets on the same row?

Comment: Oh yeah i mean row not column, and yes i want some padding between them but i found no other way

Comment: Are you aware that `grid` has options named `padx` and `ipadx`?